# how to use protocol and delegate methods for viewcontroller that are not directly connected?

Tags: swift, delegates, protocols

Im new to swift and iOS development.I have a doubt regarding protocol and delegate methods.

I have a 4 vc's say vc1,vc2,vc3,vc4.And i'm navigating from vc1->vc2->vc3-vc4->vc1. That is from vc4, im poping using navigation controller back to vc1.

i have a protocol and methods in it like

```
protocol myProtocol{

func myFunc()

}
```

In vc4, im making a delegate as,

```
var delegate:myProtocol?
```

and im  using it in a button action as

```
if let delegate = self.delegate{

delegate.myFunc()
}
```

and also pop vc4 back to vc1.

Now in VC1,im extending myProtocol as

```
class vc1:myProtocol{

override func viewDidLoad()
{

let vcProtocol = vc4()
vc4.delegate = self

}

func myFunc()
{
print("executing this")

}

}
```

But its not working. Can i do like this?
How can i connect these to classes with delegate and protocol.Please help me

Comment: when you are in `vc1`'s `-viewDidLoad` method... where do you get the instance of `vc4` from? because that local variable you are using is a completely different instance from which will be created by `vc3` _later_ or optionally maybe _never_ in a standard view lifecycle.

Answer (score 0):

viewDidLoad is only executed once if the controller is not destroyed.

Try calling in viewWillAppear for example.

Also, you do not need to change the delegate of vc4, just set the delegate to vc1 again (in viewWillAppear).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Notification?
In your VC1 ViewController ViewDidLoad method:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(myFunc, name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "aNotificationName"), object: nil)
```

In your VC4 when the myFunc is needed:

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("aNotificationName"), object: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the viewController from the navigation stack which has the same type as your first viewController and then assign it as the delegate object in your vc4.

For instance:
In vc4's viewDidLoad, you may do this

```
for viewController in self.navigationController?.viewControllers{
if viewController.isKindOfClass(YourVC1ControllerType){
    self.delegate = viewController
}
}
```

I assume that your vc1,vc2,vc3, etc have their own ViewController custom classes.

Another way of implementing this would be to get the first controller from the self.navigationController?.viewControllers array and setting it as the delegate object in vc4.

```
//In viewDidLoad of vc4
 delegate = self.navigationController?.viewControllers.first as! HomeController
```

or,

```
 //In viewDidLoad of vc4
 delegate = self.navigationController?.viewControllers.[indexOfTheController] as! HomeController
```